# Как передать массив в функцию?

Tags: c++, c++-faq

Нужно чтобы массив был как входной параметр.

```
void f (int &heap[])
{

}
```

На код выше компилятор ругается.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Надеюсь, теперь будет понятнее.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void
elem2 (int a[], int v)
{
  a[2] = v*v;
}

int
main ()
{
  int a[3] = {1,2,3};

  elem2(a,10);

  return printf("elem[2] = %d\n",a[2]) == EOF;
}

c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $ gcc a.c
c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $ ./a
elem[2] = 100
c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $ echo $?
0
c:/Documents and Settings/avp/src/hashcode $
```

Если что-то не понятно, спрашивайте.

Answer (score 11):

Правильный синтаксис ссылки на массив - это

```
void f(int (&arr)[123]) {}
```

Если размер массива неизвестен, то можно использовать шаблон:

```
template<std::size_t N> void f(int (&arr)[N]) {}
```

Если то что передается в функцию - это не массив, а указатель (т.е. не `T[N]` a `T*`), то функция должна принимать указатель, а размер надо передавать дополнительным параметром или как-то еще.

```
void f(int* ptr, std::size_t n) {}
```

Однако это очень ненадежное решение, нет никакой гарантии что будет передан правильный размер массива, или что `ptr` не равен `nullptr`.
По этому правильно - это использовать `span<T>` из [C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#i13-do-not-pass-an-array-as-a-single-pointer)

```
void f(gsl::span<T> arr) {}
```

Также, вместо массива `T[N]` можно передавать ссылку на `std::array`

```
void f(std::array<T, N>& v) {}
```

А вместо динамического массива - использовать `std::vector`:

```
void f(std::vector<T>& v) {}
-- или --
void f(const std::vector<T>& v) {}
```

Comment: Вместо `std::vector` правильнее было бы упомянуть `std::array`

Answer (score 8):

Два способа передать массив в функцию:

```
void foo (int* arr) {
....
}
```

или

```
void foo (int arr[]) {
.....    
}
```

Но при обоих способах, как было указано, имеет смысл в качестве второго (или иного) параметра передавать размер массива или как-то в самом массиве фиксировать его окончание.

Однако, в С++ все-таки лучше по возможности использовать контейнер vector или (в случае статического определения размера массива) array (из С++11 или boost.array)

Answer (score 7):

Попробуй передавать указатель на массив, если он одномерный, то:

```
void f(int* arr) { }
```

Дело в том, что в функцию передаётся указатель на массив. Можешь делать всё, что угодно с массивом внутри функции, изменения будут видны из вне. Массив не может передаваться по значению.

Comment: Этого, как правило, маловато будет.Нужно бы еще и длину массива передать. Но не всегда.

Comment: Запись

    void f(int a[]) { printf ("elem[2] = %d\n",a[2]); }
    main () {
       int arr[3] = {1,2,3};
       f(arr);
    }

тоже работает. 

Как правильно заметил @BuilderC, информация о размере массива в `f()` не передается. Это Вы сами должны обеспечить.

Comment: @avp Вы не правильно поняли вопрос , мне внутри процедуры f нужно изменить массив arr

Comment: @Евгений536, вам надо изменить значения в массиве?

Comment: @avp, можно и с размером передать:

    template <size_t Size>
    void foo(int (&arr)[Size]) {
    }

Comment: Это самообман.

Comment: @avp, это вы мне?

Comment: @Евгений536 указатель на память, где хранится массив передавайте. но соответственно **не статически** объявленный массив.

Comment: @dzhioev, а если размер массива определяется динамически?

Comment: @mikillskegg, значит, передавайте размер явно, вторым аргументом. Или используйте STL, раз уж это C++.

Comment: @mikillskegg, когда размер определяется динамически, такой вариант конечно не прокатит.

Comment: @dzhioev, естественно. А кроме того, для каждого размера массива будет создана своя функция. Если массивов много, то код может раздуться очень нехило.