# не могу найти проблему в коде, выводится мусор (массивы и указатели С++)

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

```
        // 4. Написать функции:
    //4.1.Заповнення массива;
    //4.2.Вывод одномерного массива на экран (функция получает указатель на первый элемент массива)
    //4.3.Выводу элементов массива, которые стоят на четных местах, на экран (функция получает указатель на третий элемент массива)

    void FillArr(int arr, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        arr = rand() % 10;
    }
}

void ShowArr(int arr, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << arr << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void ShowElement(int arr, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 2)
    {
        cout << arr << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    const int size = 10;
    int arr[size];
    int* parr = &arr[0];

    FillArr(*arr, size);
    ShowArr(*arr, size);
    ShowElement(*arr, size);
}
```

Comment: *Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей* - код вы привели. А где *желаемое поведение, конкретная проблема или ошибка*? Или ваш вопрос надо понимать так, что никаких проблем нет, раз вы ее не можете найти, и вы просто захотели похвастаться? :)

Comment: после запуска программы выводится мусор

Comment: ***`"...не могу найти проблему в коде..."`*** и не найдете, пока не прочтете **внимательно** хоть какой-то учебник по Си

Answer (score 2):

Ну давайте разберем ваш код.

```
void FillArr(int arr, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        arr = rand() % 10;
    }
}
```

Аргументу (т.е. локальной переменнной) `arr` присваивается случайное значение `size` раз. Ни на что вне функции не влияет...

```
void ShowArr(int arr, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << arr << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

`size` раз выводится переданное значение `arr`.

```
void ShowElement(int arr, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 2)
    {
        cout << arr << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

То же самое, только вывод `size/2` раз.

```
const int size = 10;
int arr[size];
int* parr = &arr[0];     // Неаонятно зачем

FillArr(*arr, size);     // Ничего не делает
ShowArr(*arr, size);     // 10 раз выводит значение `arr[0]`
ShowElement(*arr, size); // 5 раз выводит значение `arr[0]`
```

Ну, а поскольку массив не инициализирован - выводить может что угодно. Но одно и то же значение 10 и 5 раз!

Comment: а как это исправить?

Comment: @that_drowning_man [Как передать массив в функцию?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/136769/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e)

Comment: Передавать в функции не `int`, а указатель `int*`. И обязательно почитать учебники о работе с массивами!